# Error Trying to get property of non-object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pass two variables (post and answer) to the question.blade view as I click the "submit" button while storing body, pros, cons in the DB. 
I receive the following error :

Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\wamp\www\xxxxxxxxxx\resources\views\Question.blade.php)
in 9e68b64a739caa46ec7f5af26c6c40a6cf68ebf3.php line 9
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44

The controller code :

```
  public function postAnswer(Request $request, $post_id)
        {

          $post = Post::where('id', $post_id)->first();


            $body = $request['body'];
            $pros = $request['pros'];
            $cons = $request['cons'];

            $answer = new Answer();
            $answer->body = $body;
            $answer->pros = $pros;
            $answer->cons = $cons;


    $request->user()->answers()->save($answer);
    $post->answers()->save($answer);

        return view('Question', [
            'post' => $post ,
         'answer' => $answer]);
```

The question.blade code :

```
@foreach ($answer as $answers)

                <p>{{ $answers->body }}</p>
                 <p>{{ $answers->pros }}</p>
                  <p>{{ $answers->cons }}</p>

 @endforeach
```

Comment: You can't use $answer on foreach. Just remove the foreach and use $answer to get the attributes.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But in my case I have many answers for one question, and I need to loop in the answer table ?

Comment: Then you want to loop through $post->answers instead...

Comment: As I use the $post->answers, no error appears, but nothing shows in the question.blade view, although there is answers associated to this question.  Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending `$answer` as a single object but using it in the blade as an array, either try using it directly in the blade without the @foreach, or maybe you are actually trying to send an array of answers, then send `$request->user()->answers` or `$post->answers`

Comment: This saved the data correctly in the DB. But nothing appears in the question.blade although there is answers associated to this question .... Any ideas ?

Comment: `$post->answers()` and `$request->user()->answers()` will return a query builder. To get the answers, use `$post->answers` or `$request->user()->answers`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing 'answer' => $answer, you need to pass `'answer' => $request->user()->answers()->latest()->first()`